# How can I use the WooCommerce REST API in an Android app?

Tags: java, php, android

I have generated the key and secret now I don't know how to use the key and secret so that I can get the data from server into my Android app. Can anyone tell the the proper procedure of it? How can i Create the signature , nonce and other things t authenticate ?

Answer (score -1):

Using Volley library is the easiest way to connect to APIs. For example

```
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    String url = this.apiURl; //you could store it as config at raw

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                // do nice things with your beautiful response 


            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // Handle error if any 

                }
            });

    queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

Woocommerce sends json response so use the `JsonObjectRequest`so you need not convert the String to Json again.

Hope this helps!

Comment: What To do with Consumer Key And Consumer Secret ?

Comment: if you have checked the woocommerce REST api doc you can put those keys as query params

Comment: how can i put the key and secret for Auth ?

Comment: `?consumer_key={}&consumer_secret={}`

Comment: Sir i know how to work with http request and i have tried this..
i have tried sending the consumer_key and cosumer_secret as the params ...
But i got an error here 
{
    "code": "woocommerce_rest_cannot_view",
    "message": "Sorry, you cannot list resources.",
    "data": {
        "status": 401
    }
}

Comment: It is not just using volley, it needs to provide the way to set up basic auth